# Factorial of odds

Tags: combinatorics, functions, factorial, fractions, products

I am trying to find a simple factorial of all the preceding odd numbers. If $9$ were to be picked the equation would read $9\times 7\times 5\times 3\times 1$ (only odd numbers can be picked). Would the following fraction work?

> > $$\dfrac{x!}{2^{\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)!}$$

Comment: Alternatively, use double factorial: $9!!$

Comment: I edited and I believe this is what you mean by the fraction with the brackets. When I write $ab!$, this is not equal to $(ab)!$, but rather equal to $a\cdot b!$

Comment: Another alternative is to use the Gamma function.  $\frac {\Gamma(\frac {2n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac 12)} = \frac 12\cdot \frac 32\cdot \frac 52\ \cdots\frac {n-1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

That formula doesn't work. To find one that does, notice that
$$(2n-1)\times (2n-3) \times \cdots \times 5 \times 3 \times 1$$
is what you get by dividing $(2n)!$ by the following product:
$$2n \times (2n-2) \times \cdots \times 6 \times 4 \times 2$$
Each of the terms in this product has a factor of $2$. Pulling all of them out to the front yields a nice closed-form expression in terms of exponents and factorials.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
\begin{align}
9\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1&= \frac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6 \cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{8\cdot6\cdot4\cdot2}\\&= \frac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6 \cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{2^4(4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1)}\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)[2\cdot4\cdots(2n)]}{2^n n!}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's think this out.  We want:

$N =\frac {(2n + 1)!}{\prod_{m\text{ is even}; m < 2n+1} m}=\frac {(2n + 1)!}{\prod_{k=1}^n 2k}=\frac {(2n + 1)!}{2^n\prod_{k=1}^n k}=\frac {(2n+1)!}{2^n n!}$

Okay, Replace $x=2n + 1$ and $n=\frac {x-1}2$ and we get

$N = \frac {x!}{2^{\frac {x-1}2}(\frac {x-1}2)!}$

But... if you think about this, it doesn't actually make anything easier.  There's no reason that $n! = \prod_{k \le n} k$ is any more fundamental a concept or operation than $n!! = \prod_{k\text{ is same even/oddness as }n; k \le n} k$.  And we *can* and do simply define the double factorial as exactly that.

But if you want to convert (for calculation purposes between factorial and double factorials that is the formula:

$n!! =\frac {x!}{2^{\frac {x-1}2}(\frac {x-1}2)!}$  is $x$ is odd and

$n!! =\frac {x!}{2^{\frac {x}2}(\frac {x}2)!}$

or in general $n!! =\frac {x!}{2^{\lfloor \frac {x}2\rfloor}(\lfloor \frac {x}2\rfloor)!}$

where $\lfloor y\rfloor$ is the floor function (greatest integer equal or less than).